# PHP Paypal error when customer places second order on express checkout API

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

When I have a customer place a Paypal order the first order goes through fine.  If they place another order right away it will give this error:

> A successful transaction has already been completed for this token.

Any ideas how I can clear this up so they can place another order immediately?

getExpressCheckout

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {


$API_UserName = PAYPAL_USER;
$API_Password = PAYPAL_PASS;
$API_Signature = PAYPAL_SIGNATURE;
$version = PAYPAL_VERSION;

$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
if ("sandbox" === PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT || "-sandbox" === PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT) {
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t." . PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT . ".paypal.com/nvp";
}

//$version = urlencode('63.0');
// Set the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

// Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
$nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

// Get response from the server.
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$httpResponse) {
    exit('$methodName_ failed: ' . curl_error($ch) . '(' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');
}

// Extract the response details.
$httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

$httpParsedResponseAr = array();
foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
    $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
    if (sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
        $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
    }
}

if ((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
    exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
}

return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Obtain the token from PayPal.
if (!array_key_exists('token', $_REQUEST)) {
    exit('Token is not received.');
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['token']));

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token";

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $nvpStr);

if ("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    // Extract the response details.
    $payerID = $httpParsedResponseAr['PAYERID'];
    $fname = $httpParsedResponseAr['FIRSTNAME'];
    $lname = $httpParsedResponseAr['LASTNAME'];
    $street1 = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET"];
    if (array_key_exists("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2", $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        $street2 = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2"];
    }
    $city_name = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY"];
    $state_province = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE"];
    $postal_code = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP"];
    $country_code = $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE"];

//    $_SESSION['st_fname'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($fname));
//    $_SESSION['st_lname'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($lname));
//    $_SESSION['st_address'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($street1));
//    $_SESSION['st_address2'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($street2));
//    $_SESSION['st_city'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($city_name));
//    $_SESSION['st_state'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($state_province));
//    $_SESSION['st_zip'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($postal_code));
    $_SESSION['pp_token'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr['TOKEN']));
    $_SESSION['pp_payerid'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr['PAYERID']));
    $_SESSION['pp_email'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr['EMAIL']));
    $_SESSION['pp_phone'] = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr['PHONE']));
    $_SESSION['paymentType'] = "paypal";





    //echo 'Get Express Checkout Details Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true);
    header('Location: ' . $path . '/paypal_do.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['cc_msg'] = "Paypal payment failed.  Please try again";
    //print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
    header('Location: ' . $path . '/pay.php');

    //exit('GetExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
```

SetExpressCheckout

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {



$API_UserName = PAYPAL_USER;
$API_Password = PAYPAL_PASS;
$API_Signature = PAYPAL_SIGNATURE;
$version = PAYPAL_VERSION;

$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
if ("sandbox" === PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT || "-sandbox" === PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT) {
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t." . PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT . ".paypal.com/nvp";
}

//$version = urlencode('63.0');
// Set the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

// Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
$nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);



// Get response from the server.
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$httpResponse) {
    exit("$methodName_ failed: " . curl_error($ch) . '(' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');
}

// Extract the response details.
$httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

$httpParsedResponseAr = array();
foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
    $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
    if (sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
        $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
    }
}

if ((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
    exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
}

return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.

$paymentAmount = urlencode(number_format($_SESSION['grandTotal'], 2));
$currencyID = urlencode('USD');       // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
$paymentType = urlencode('Sale');    // or 'Sale' or 'Order'

$returnURL = urlencode($path . "/paypal_get.php");
$cancelURL = urlencode($path . "/pay.php");

/*

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE session_id = '".session_id()."'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $count = 0;

  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ".$rows['item_id'];
  $results = mysql_query($sql);
  $item_row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM frame_options WHERE id = ".$rows['frame_id'];
  $results = mysql_query($sql);
  $item_frame = mysql_fetch_array($results);

  //build the item row
  $item = $item_row['width']." x ".$item_row['height']." ".$rows['finish_id'];


  $nvpStr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME".$count."=".$item;
  $nvpStr .= "&L_PAYMENT_REQUEST_0_QTY".$count."=".$rows['qty'];
  $nvpStr .= "&L_PAYMENT_REQUEST_0_AMT".$count."=".$rows['price'];

  $count++;

  }
  if(isset($_SESSION['discount']) && $_SESSION['discount'] <> 0){
  $nvpStr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME".$count."=Discount";
  $nvpStr .= "&L_PAYMENT_REQUEST_0_QTY".$count."=1";
  $nvpStr .= "&L_PAYMENT_REQUEST_0_AMT".$count."=-".$_SESSION['discount'];
  }

  //determine shipping cost

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM shipping_options WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['shipping_option'];
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $shipping_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  $paymentAmount = $paymentAmount - $shipping_rows['rate'] - $_SESSION['sales_tax'];

  $nvpStr .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT = ".$shipping_row['rate'];

  $sql = "SELECT SUM(price) as itemTotal FROM cart WHERE session_id = '".session_id()."'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $itemTotal_row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $nvpStr .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT = ".$itemTotal_row['itemTotal'];
 */
// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$paymentAmount&RETURNURL=$returnURL&CANCELURL=$cancelURL&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";
$nvpStr .= "&HDRIMG=" . $path . "/images/logo_white_background.png&useraction=commit";






echo $nvpStr;



// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);


if ("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    // Redirect to paypal.com.
    $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);
    $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token&useraction=commit";
    if ("sandbox" === $environment || "-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    }
    header("Location: $payPalURL");
    exit;
} else {
    exit('SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
```

DoExpressCheckout

```
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {



$API_UserName = PAYPAL_USER;
$API_Password = PAYPAL_PASS;
$API_Signature = PAYPAL_SIGNATURE;       
$version = PAYPAL_VERSION;

$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
if ("sandbox" === PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT || "-sandbox" === PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT) {
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t." . PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT . ".paypal.com/nvp";
}

 //$version = urlencode('63.0');

// setting the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

// Set the curl parameters.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
$nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

// Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

// Get response from the server.
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

if (!$httpResponse) {
    exit('$methodName_ failed: ' . curl_error($ch) . '(' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');
}

// Extract the response details.
$httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

$httpParsedResponseAr = array();
foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
    $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
    if (sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
        $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
    }
}

if ((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
    exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
}

return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

/**
 * This example assumes that a token was obtained from the SetExpressCheckout API call.
 * This example also assumes that a payerID was obtained from the SetExpressCheckout API call
 * or from the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call.
 */
// Set request-specific fields.
$payerID = urlencode($_SESSION['pp_payerid']);
$token = urlencode($_SESSION['pp_token']);

$paymentType = urlencode("Sale");   // or 'Sale' or 'Order'
$paymentAmount = urlencode(number_format($_SESSION['grandTotal'], 2));
$currencyID = urlencode("USD");      // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token&PAYERID=$payerID&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$paymentAmount&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $nvpStr);


if ("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || 
        "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    $_SESSION['paypal_transaction_id'] = $httpParsedResponseAr['TRANSACTIONID'];

    cartToOrder();


    redirect("order_confirmation.php");
    exit('Express Checkout Payment Completed Successfully: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
} else {
    exit('DoExpressCheckoutPayment failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is to add many products in one session using one token?

Comment: I would recommend you to consider if you should add some code to this question?

Comment: @pavel I have added the code for the three steps in paypal express checkout that I am using.  Let me know if you need to see any other code.

Comment: You must use method GetExpressCheckoutDetails AFTER method SetExpressCheckout. You will needed from TOKEN setted by SetExpressCheckout. Just change the order of methods

Answer (score 0):

First, with one TOKEN ( on one http request ) you have option to create one session with products. If you use some of API method ( DoExpressCheckoutPayment, CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, etc ) you will consumed this token! Other option is to expire the time of current token but in this case error message will be different than "A successful transaction has already been completed for this token."

So you must use again SetExpressCheckout API method to get another token.

Comment: I am using another SetExpressCheckout.  I complete the process again after each order.  Is it possible that the paypal token is being saved in a session and not being overwritten one the second since it is already set?  I guess I could just clear the session for the paypal token but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Each token is associated with products and details that is been set with method SetExpressCheckout. Please provide some code